# AJAX submit function optimization

Tags: forms, jquery

I have a form on my site. A series of functions validate each form field on the form `#contactForm`

I have the following submit function which, if all the fields are valid, sends an ajax request to `contact-us.php` and then shows a success message. The function works, but I'm wondering if this is the ideal way to have this coded (especially with the two (2) `return false` statements).

Here's part of my code:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function(e){ 
    if(validateContactFirstName() && validateContactLastName() && validateContactEmail() && validateContactPhone() && validateContactMessage()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#contactSubmit').button('loading');
                $('#contactSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $.ajax({
                            type    : 'POST',
                            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
                            data    : $(this).serialize(),
                            success : function(data) {
                                            $('.hideOnSuccess').hide();
                                            $('div.contactSuccess').html('<div class="hero-unit"><h1><i class="icon-envelope-alt successIcon"></i> Thanks!</h1><p>An email confirming the details of your message has been sent to your email address. We will respond within one business day. </p></div>');                         
                                            $('html,body').animate({
                                                    scrollTop: 0
                                            }, 800);
                            }
                });
                return false;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
});
```

Which `return false` statements can I remove? Or should I take out the `preventDefault` ?

Comment: If you always want to `return false;`, just put it after the `if/else` block before the end of the function.

Comment: Can you provide the whole block of code with comments on what you're suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't be much of an answer. Honestly your code doesn't need any improvement besides the above comment. If it's working fine, why complicate things?

Comment: So remove the two `return false` statements, and just put one before the closing `});` ?

Comment: Can you look at my updated code - Look at the edit - I'm not sure what I did lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer using $.post which is a shorthand of what you're using.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Also, be sure to prevent default for your form submission - would look like this

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(validateContactFirstName() && validateContactLastName() && validateContactEmail() && validateContactPhone() && validateContactMessage()) {
                $('#contactSubmit').button('loading');
                $('#contactSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $.ajax({
                            type    : 'POST',
                            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
                            data    : $(this).serialize(),
                            success : function(data) {
                                            $('.hideOnSuccess').hide();
                                            $('div.contactSuccess').html('<div class="hero-unit"><h1><i class="icon-envelope-alt successIcon"></i> Thanks!</h1><p>An email confirming the details of your message has been sent to your email address. We will respond within one business day. </p></div>');                         
                                            $('html,body').animate({
                                                    scrollTop: 0
                                            }, 800);
                            }
                });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Do I need the `serialize` or `dataType` calls in the code at all?

Comment: Also (since he deleted his answer) where would the prevent default go?

Comment: You can but don't have to. Scroll down to the examples on the page I linked, should answer your questions.

Comment: If you're returning `false` from the event handler, you don't need `e.preventDefault`. One or the other will suffice (although they don't do exactly the same thing).

Comment: It's actually not working via Ajax now - I've updated my code... what's wrong?

Comment: Update your original post with what you have and I'll see if I can help

Comment: Ok - updated the code in the original question. I think it's working now - does it look OK? Or do I not need both of the `return false` statements?

Comment: No need for both return false statements, simply putting it at the end will make sure it returns as you were returning false no matter what. I update my post which should work for you provided everything else works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it with the [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and provide only the callback.

You can leave only one `return false` at the end of the function and remove the else.